# finding clients with no activity in a date range

Tags: postgresql

The query below allows for me to monitor what services have been performed in a date range.  I also modify it to show the last "X" days.

Here is my problem.  I need to find all clients that have had NO activity in a date range.  I have seen examples using left outer joins 
( http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/11/sql-outer-joins.html )  and tried to follow it, but the result no "missing" services would show.  I needed to see that "Bob" was not seen in the past "X" days, not the activity that did happen.

So, if someone can look at this and steer me to a solution, I'd be very thankful

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  groups.name as Office,to_char (notes.date_service,'MM/DD/YY')as DateEntered,
to_char(notes.date_creation,'MM/DD/YY')as DateService,
notes.date_creation - notes.date_service as DateDiff, 
services.code, clients.client_id,
clients.name_lastfirst_cs, staff.staff_name_cs, address.addr_county
FROM notes, services, clients, staff, groups, address
WHERE notes.zrud_service = services.zzud_service
AND notes.zrud_client = clients.zzud_client
AND notes.zrud_staff = staff.zzud_staff
AND notes.zrud_group = groups.zzud_group
AND clients.zzud_client = address.zrud_client
AND services.code IN ('10101', '10102', '10201' , '10202','10203','10204','10205','10401','10402','10403','10405') - - <I comment out this line and change it depending on the results I need >

AND groups.name = 'RCE'
AND notes.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '8 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now();  
-- this last line is also changed for diferent time spans
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that clients are stored in the table `clients`, and their activity is in the `notes` table, then use NOT EXISTS (an antijoin):

```
--  I need to find all clients .....
SELECT * FROM clients
WHERE
-- ... that have had NO activity ....
  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1 FROM notes
     WHERE  notes.zrud_client = clients.zzud_client
-- ...  in a date range.
       AND notes.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '8 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now()
  )
```

The above antijoin can be converted to left outer join in this way:

```
SELECT clients.* FROM clients
LEFT JOIN notes
ON ( 
     notes.zrud_client = clients.zzud_client
     AND 
     notes.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '8 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now() 
   )
WHERE 
  notes.zrud_client IS NULL
```

Comment: Kordirko -  Thanks so much for steering me into the correct direction.  I tried with the last WHERE statement commented to see how that went, and as you suggested.  Then I added several notes to clients that appeared in the report to see if they would disappear in another query and they do.

Answer (score 0):

Tha main parts of answer are

- use proper ANSI joins;
- format your query;
- use aliases for table;

So your query becomes:

```
select
    g.name as Office,
    to_char(n.date_service,'MM/DD/YY') as DateEntered,
    to_char(n.date_creation,'MM/DD/YY') as DateService,
    n.date_creation - n.date_service as DateDiff, 
    s.code, c.client_id,
    c.name_lastfirst_cs, st.staff_name_cs, a.addr_county
from notes as n
    inner join services as s on s.zzud_service = n.zrud_service
    inner join clients as c on c.zzud_client = n.zrud_client
    inner join staff as st on st.zzud_staff = n.zrud_staff
    inner join groups as g on g.zzud_group = n.zrud_group
    inner join address as a on a.zrud_client = c.zzud_client
where
    g.name = 'RCE' and 
    s.code in ('10101', '10102', '10201', '10202','10203','10204','10205','10401','10402','10403','10405') and
    n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '8 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now();
```

But if you want to get all clients even if they have no activity in notes in given period, I think you want `clients` to be anchor of you query, use `left outer join` and move conditions into `join` instead of `where`

```
select
    c.client_id,
    c.name_lastfirst_cs, st.staff_name_cs, a.addr_county,
    g.name as Office,
    to_char(n.date_service,'MM/DD/YY') as DateEntered,
    to_char(n.date_creation,'MM/DD/YY') as DateService,
    n.date_creation - n.date_service as DateDiff, 
    s.code
from clients as c
    inner join address as a on a.zrud_client = c.zzud_client
    left outer join notes as n on n.zrud_client = c.zzud_client and n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '8 days'::interval)::timestamp AND now()
    left outer join services as s on s.zzud_service = n.zrud_service and s.code in ('10101', '10102', '10201', '10202','10203','10204','10205','10401','10402','10403','10405')
    left outer join staff as st on st.zzud_staff = n.zrud_staff
    left outer join groups as g on g.zzud_group = n.zrud_group and g.name = 'RCE'
```